# How would I go about creating a ReturnAlteredObject extension method?

Tags: c#, clone, extension-methods

**TL;DR:** I want an extension method that can extend object and can be used like this:

```
var OtherInstance = MyObject.Altered(new { Prop1 = "123", Prop6 = 4 });
```

I'd expect all properties of `OtherInstance` to be the same as `MyObject`, except for `Prop1` and `Prop6`. I don't expect/require it to deep-clone.

---

### Background

I have an MVC page that allows the user to search to display a list of data.

My page model has various filter properties, as well as a page number.

At the bottom of my list of data I have a link to the next page created using `Html.ActionLink`. I pass in a copy of the model, with the page number incremented:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Next", "Index", new
{
    Page = (Model.Page ?? -1) + 1,
    Model.SortProperties,
    Model.SortDescending,
    Model.FilterId,
    Model.FilterApprovalsLevelId,
    Model.FilterStandardTypeId,
    Model.FilterApprovalsBodyReferenceNumber,
    Model.FilterCertificateOrApprovalNumber
}, new { id = "next-page" })%>
```

If I add new filters to my model it's easy to forget to add the property in here, so I was hoping to be able to clone the object and alter 1 or 2 properties fluently, like so:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Next", "Index", Model.Altered(new
{
    Page = (Model.Page ?? -1) + 1
}), new { id = "next-page" })%>
```

Comment: Have you considered making your viewmodel an `ExpandoObject` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RouteValueDictionary class to achive that. First Create and instance of RouteValueDictionary from your model and then add to the dictionary the rest of the properties here is the pseudo code:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Next", "Index", new RouteValueDictionary(Model).AddAndReturn("Page", (Model.Page ?? -1) + 1), new { id = "next-page" })%>
```

Comment: Where is `AddAndReturn` defined? I got a method not found error.

Comment: This is a pseuode code. You need to write this extension method for the RouteValueDictionary class. The method will call Add metohd of RouteValueDictionary clas and return the dictionary

Comment: Here is the signature of the extension method:                  public static RouteValueDictionary AddAndReturn(this RouteValueDictionary dict, string propertyName, object value){dict.Add(propertyName, value); return dict;}

Comment: Ahh I see, I thought it was something built in.